# Select only direct children from element with Sass

Tags: css, sass

Lets say I have the following html:

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="logo">
        <img src="#" alt="Logo">
    </div>

    <div class="account">
        <div class="options">
        </div>

        <div class="search">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

And I have the following SCSS:

```
header {
    height: 4.1rem;

    div {
        width: 33%;
        float: left;
        height: 4.1rem;
        line-height: 4.1rem;
        color: #fff;

        &.title {
            h1 {
                font-weight: normal;
                font-size: 3rem;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
        }

        &.logo {
            text-align: center;
        }

        &.account {
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem that I have is that divs `options` and `search` are 33% percent of `account` which is logic as I have `div {width: 33%}`. I know I can select direct child elements with:

```
header {
  > div {
  }
}
```

But this doesn't help even if I put the `>` infront of all other classes. I also know I can say that the width should be 0 or what ever again in `.account` but I would like to prevent this.

Comment: What does this have to do with Sass?  If you have a pure CSS problem, only post the compiled CSS.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Try this:

```
    ...
    & > div {width: 33%;}

    div {
      float: left;
      height: 4.1rem;
      line-height: 4.1rem;
      color: #fff;
      ...
```

Take out div width and apply it only on direct children. Leave rest as is. 
Here is quick [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d8pto5pa/) (remove `.option` and `.search` styles later, its only for visualisation).

Please edit your question and better explain what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: the ampersand is unnecessary, it compiles to the same thing without it. https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Answer (score 27):

Use the `&` with `>` inside the parent element like this:

```css
.services {
    & > div {
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
}
```

Comment: the ampersand is unnecessary https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Answer (score 6):

I am not certain I understand you. But I think you want a combination of direct children and child pseudo selectors, in pure CSS:

```
header > div:first-child {
}
```

Or, for the second div:

```
header > div:nth-child(2) {
}
```

You could also use the `not` selector:

```
header > div:not(.account) {
}
```

to exclude any unwanted div's.

Comment: These aren't really working for me. Option 1 would only work for `.title`. Option 2 It doesn't apply for second div. Option 3 this would not apply certain style under div

Comment: Or, perhaps: `header > div, header > div > div {}`?

Comment: Turns out `header > div {}` was what you wanted, I'm not sure how you applied it, but that would be the same as the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`:scope` also works.
Just prepend `:scope` to your `<` direct descendant selector.

```scss
header {
  :scope > div {
    // styles
  }
}
```